# How can I change pdf page size?

Tags: pdf

I would like to split pages in pdf so that each page would be divided into 2 pages ( e.g. form 100 pages I would go into 200 but smaller - exactly half size).

I need this to read pdfs on my ebook reader.

Anybody knows how can this be done ?

Comment: https://github.com/ciju/split-pdf-slides Its a tool to convert 8/6/4/2-up pdfs to 1-up. Disclaimer: I am the author. Would have replied as a comment, but don't have enough reputation to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Briss**](http://briss.sourceforge.net/) might be just the tool you need. Make sure Java (JRE) is installed, and be sure to read the linked reviews on the download page, although the program's quite easy to use.

> This project aims to offer a simple cross-platform (Linux, Windows, Mac OSX) application for cropping PDF files. A simple user interface lets you define exactly the crop-region by fitting a rectangle on the visually overlaid pages.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to Briss is [PDF Scissors](http://www.pdfscissors.tools/) ([alternative site](https://sites.google.com/site/pdfscissors/)). The logic is almost the same as Briss. In my opinion Briss is more powerful but less user-friendly. I use both.

Comment: New links: http://www.pdfscissors.tools / https://sites.google.com/site/pdfscissors/