# Adding margin to rasterized PDF using ghostscript

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, linux-terminal

I'm cropping and rasterizing some PDFs using ImageMagick. In order to remove some text that I don't need, I want to crop to a smaller box than needed and then readjusting the page size adding some white space.

To rasterize and crop, i proceed as follows:

```
for filename in *.eps; do
    convert -density 150 -crop "$bbwpx"x"$bbhpx"+"$xoffpx"+"$yoffpx" \
      +repage "$filename" "${filename%.*}.png"
    convert "${filename%.*}.png" "${filename%.*}.pdf"
done
```

Following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/905279/702760), I then want to increase the height of the page. Therefore I added one more line to the code shown above to get:

```
for filename in *.eps; do
    convert -density 150 -crop "$bbwpx"x"$bbhpx"+"$xoffpx"+"$yoffpx" \
       +repage "$filename" "${filename%.*}.png"
    convert "${filename%.*}.png" "${filename%.*}.pdf"
    gs -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile="${filename%.*}-crop.pdf"\
      -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS="$bbw" -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS="$bbhnew" -dFIXEDMEDIA -c \
      "<< /CurrPageNum 1 def /Install {0 $bbcorr translate} bind  >> \
      setpagedevice" -f "${filename%.*}.pdf"
done
```

However, after running this, the height always remains the same as before (as shown by `pdfinfo`), the content of the pdf is however correctly translated.

Running the code on not rasterized PDFs works, though.